# Python Pythagoras' Theorem validation

Tags: validation, python-3.x

I have to create a program which uses Pythagoras' theorem and I have to validate the inputs. I have been asked in the pseudocode to:

```
get Input()
1.1 initialize check
1.2 repeat check while check = true
1.3   input the length of 1st short side
1.4 return validated number
1.5 End repeat
```

So far i have

```
def MAIN():
print('This program is designed for the purpose of determining whether a triangle is right angled or not')

#This function is designed to take the input from the user.
def GET_INPUT():
    input > 1
    ShortSide1 = float(input('please enter the length of the first short side.')
                    while false:
                    print('invalid entry ')
                    else:
                    return ShortSide1
MAIN()
```

Comment: The pseudocode is a bit weird (and wrong).  I would not want to turn that into code myself.  Use lowercase for function names.

Answer (score 2):

Where are you stuck? Said in an other way, what is it that you need help with?

PS:
I would use raw_input instead of input, the latter tries to evaluate the input given by the user. With input() you can input code directly into the program.

Comment: In 3.x, 'input' *is* 2.7's 'raw_input'.  Check the tags.